# Performance with query that filters on document path

Tags: caml-query, performance

My CAML Query on a large Pages library based on a folder structure takes too long (15-20 seconds), and I wonder how I could optimize this. I currently use a filter where

```
FileRef BeginsWith [specific path with subfolders]
```

Is `FileRef` an indexed column by default or not? Would `EncodedAbsUrl` be a better option than `FileRef`?

I realize that I would be better off if I used a `Choice` column and an `Equals` filter instead, but a folder structure still seems to be easier to understand for our end users, compared to tagging each item.

Answer (score 1):

Certain things can optimize it if you haven't used:-

1) Get only those columns which you require eg if you need only Title and FileReaf column then use like the below one

query.ViewFields = string.Concat("",
                                   "");

2) Set row limit

It would be more easier if you can provide number of pages in that library and your caml query

Thanks.